# Help with HelloWorld Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm Very new to Objective-C iPhone programming. I'm kinda gonna go with the trial-and-error method on this one:P. So my question has to do with getting a name. Here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)sayHello:(id)sender{
NSString *name = [textField text];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello ", name];
```

What this does is get the text from a UITextField (I already have this setup) and outputs to a UILabel. I would think this would work, but apparently not, because it just outputs "Hello ". Missing the name. Help would be appreciated :)

Thanks,

Eric

EDIT: Thanks to all that responded. It worked! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should read:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", name];
```

`stringWithFormat` uses "%" sequences to insert values into the string it's building. You use different "%" sequences depending on what type of value you're inserting: "%@" is for Objective-C objects, "%d" is for integers, and so forth. You can insert multiple values by using multiple "%" sequences, for example:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@ %@ and your %d friends", firstName, lastName, 7];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", name];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)sayHello:(id)sender{
  NSString *name = [textField text];
  label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", name];
}
```

You have to add `%@`, so that it will place your name string in the formatted string.

Answer (score 1):

You need a format specifier:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", name];
```

The %@ format specifier means "an NSObject reference". For formatting other datatypes - int, double, etc. you should use %d, %f and so on.